# Не заходит в админку Wordpress после установки мультисайтовости

Tags: wordpress

Сегодня установил мультисайтовость на ВП, всё было ок. Потом что-то не много намутил и поехала вёрстка, развернул бэкап БД и файлов. Устанавливаю мультисайтовость заного, после чего выкидывает из лк ( как и должно ). Только вот, обратно уже не входит. При введение правильного логина и пароля ничего не происходит, а если ввести неправильную комбинацию - ошибка о неправильно введённом логине/пароле.

Куда копать?

p.s. невозможно зайти с любого юзера

Comment: В первую очередь проверьте журнал ошибок PHP на хостинге

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо зайти в "Управление сетью - Пользователи" (/wp-admin/network/users.php) - проверить назначен ли пользователь для сайтов (последняя колонка "Сайты")

Если нет - можно в "Управление сетью - Сайты" (/wp-admin/network/sites.php) назначить пользователя для нужных сайтов

Comment: Чтобы туда зайти, нужен доступ в админку :( А я не могу залогиниться

Comment: @Ex1st при установке мультисайта сделали все необходимые изменения для wp-config.php и  .htaccess ?

Comment: Конечно. Надо добавить, что сегодня всё работало, пока не намутил с бэкапами и работать перестало

Comment: @Ex1st возможно какая-то проблема с куками. попробуйте в wp-config.php прописать define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', strtolower( stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ) );

Comment: Удивительно, но после очередного разворота бэкапа заработало. Магия.